# Kotlin REPL Arithmetic

Tags: kotlin, read-eval-print-loop

I just got started with a book on Kotlin and guess what? yes I can't figure out anything. Here is the thing
just by using REPL you can run part of your code and see if it runs without the need of creating a new file but I got a beautiful error message when I try to do min (43, -33), or any min(), max() and so on.

here is the error examples:

max(22, 33)
**error: unresolved reference. None of the following candidates is applicable because of receiver type mismatch:**

min(93, -99)
**error: unresolved reference. None of the following candidates is applicable because of receiver type mismatch:
public fun <T : Comparable<TypeVariable(T)>> Array<out TypeVariable(T)>.min(): TypeVariable(T)? defined in kotlin.collections
public fun Array.min(): Double? defined in kotlin.collections**

Thanks to all and appreciate any help!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `min()` and `max()` funtions are not part of the core language, the are defined in the standard library in the `kotlin.math` package. You need to import the package, than you can use these methods:

```
import kotlin.math.*
min(22, 33)
```

Comment: Or you can use the fully-qualified versions: [`kotlin.math.min(…)`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.math/min.html) &c.